# Rails: accessing current user session in a model (

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, thread-safety, observer-pattern

Maintaining a Rails v2.3.8 app deployed on Apache with mod_passenger.

I need access to current user session in one of the models (an Auditor observer to be exact).
I know this breaks the MVC principle. But i have to violate it as I have an observer that needs to know the currently logged in user. I have a lot of controllers and placing the call to Auditor logger would not be very DRY.

I'm just trying to be able to call User.current with currently logged in user session returned. However I've ran into an issue with caching/thread-safety. The original author used a class variable (@@current) to store the current user. But this is not thread safe, so I turned it into this

```
class User < AR:Base
  ...
  def self.current
    Thread.current[:user]
  end

  def self.current=(user)
    Thread.current[:user] = user
  end
  ...
end
```

So it should be thread-safe. And in Auditor observer I have a call:

```
Auditor(subject, action, object)
```

Where I pass in User.current as subject.

This code works great in development, but in productions I get incorrect values from User.current. At times I get another logged in user's record and not the current one. So there is some thread-safety/class-caching issue that still exists, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

ActiveRecord and ActionPack are completely different so you do not have access to session/cookies in models. If you need the current user you have two options.

Option 1 - Pass the current user to the model

In your controller:

```
def index
    Audit.get_current_user(current_user)
    #where audit is your model that you will send the current_user to
end
```

Option 2 - Have a user model that performs action after a user object is modified.

In your user model:

```
before_save :adjust_user

def adjust_user
    #self will be the object that was just modified aka the current user
end
```

Comment: That is why I created the current getter/setter method that are thread-safe, it does allow me to store/obtain current user. The problem arises with calls to User.current being cached (i think).

Comment: For option 1: I can pass the current_user from the controller method directly, not sure why I need to get_current_user(). But I specifically wish to avoid having many calls to Auditor() from controllers, as there are plenty of spots that require this type of call. Observer works much more cleanly.

Comment: For option 2: I'm not following you... User object isn't the only thing that gets modified. I have various object that logged-in user can modify (like Policy, Permission, etc). Think of Auditor as an activity feed logger. Users can CRUD policies, permissions, etc. So I still have to pass current_user to Auditor model.

Comment: all I can really say is that rails MVC doesn't really allow getting the user from the model unless there is some pulgin/gem that does this.

Comment: You can also user `:touch => :model_name` to update associations.